# Can I have multiple spark versions installed in CDH?

Tags: apache-spark, cloudera-cdh

I'm using cdh5.1.0, which already has default spark installed. However, I want to use Spark 1.3. Can I also install this version to cdh5.1.0? How is it possible to set these up? Will the new version of spark also be monitored via Cloudera manager?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you can run any Apache Spark version you like. Just make sure it's built for the version of YARN you have (2.3 for CDH 5.1.0). You can then run your application as a YARN application with `spark-submit`. (See http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/running-on-yarn.html.) It will be monitored like any other YARN application.

Spark doesn't need to be "installed" at all, you just run your application.

Comment: Probably helpful to mention that the desired Spark version should be built with the given Yarn version.

Comment: how to check my current version of YARN? if the current yarn don't have spark1.3, what should be done next?

Comment: Thanks Shyamendra! I've added a sentence about that. @HappyCoding: I think CDH 5.1.0 has Hadoop 2.3, so when you download Spark 1.3.0, pick the build that says "pre-built for Hadoop 2.3".

Comment: great! thank you and @ShyamendraSolanki. In a summary, It needs to build the right version of spark and it is then submit spark job to YARN cluster.

Comment: You don't need to build it yourself, there's a pre-built binary you can download.

Comment: On the spark download page https://spark.apache.org/downloads.html,I I didn't find a pre-build version for cdh5.1.0. There could be some different for hadoop 2.3 cdh version with the standalone version. Will this version difference matter?

Comment: YARN 2.3 from Cloudera should be fully compatible with stock YARN 2.3. I think you'll be fine!

Comment: @DanielDarabos Can i have spark with CDH4.6.0? Because CDH4.6.0 provides hadoop 2.0.0 it uses only MR. No YARN there. Please let me know

Comment: If you don't have YARN, you have to run Spark in standalone mode. (You have to start the Spark master & workers yourself.) In this case the only part of Hadoop that Spark uses is HDFS. Everything else is completely independent of it.

Answer (score -4):

Please execute below commands from your console, with sudo access and password....it will update your spark current version to latest version

```
sudo yum install spark-core spark-master spark-worker spark-history-server spark-python
sudo yum install spark-core spark-history-server spark-python
```

Comment: While this might be a valuable hint to solve the problem, an
answer really needs a bit more detail than this.  Please
[edit] to explain how this answers the question.
Alternatively, consider writing this as a comment instead.