# yarn executor launch wrong version of spark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, hadoop-yarn

I had a cluster with hadoop 2.6.3 and spark 1.6 installed.

Recently, I upgraded spark to 2.0 and everything seems working fine until I tried to run some old job witn spark 1.6 which had some compatiable issue with spark 2.0.

The first thing I tried was the following:

```
echo $SPARK_HOME
/usr/local/spark-1.6.1-bin-hadoop2.6
/usr/local/spark-1.6.1-bin-hadoop2.6/bin/spark-submit  --master yarn--deploy-mode client /usr/local/spark-1.6.1-bin-hadoop2.6/examples/src/main/python/pi.py 100
```

However, the above job failed and when I checked yarn logs I found the following:

```
YARN executor launch context:
env:
CLASSPATH -> {{PWD}}<CPS>{{PWD}}/__spark__.jar<CPS>$HADOOP_CONF_DIR<CPS>$HADOOP_COMMON_HOME/share/hadoop/common/*<CPS>$HADOOP_COMMON_HOME/share/hadoop/common/lib/*<CPS>$HADOOP_HDFS_HOME/share/hadoop/hdfs/*<CPS>$HADOOP_HDFS_HOME/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/*<CPS>$HADOOP_YARN_HOME/share/hadoop/yarn/*<CPS>$HADOOP_YARN_HOME/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/*<CPS>$HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME/share/hadoop/mapreduce/*<CPS>$HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/*
SPARK_LOG_URL_STDERR -> http://datanode01-bi-dev:8042/node/containerlogs/container_1476081972773_0194_01_000003/hadoop/stderr?start=-4096
    SPARK_YARN_STAGING_DIR -> .sparkStaging/application_1476081972773_0194
    SPARK_YARN_CACHE_FILES_FILE_SIZES -> 187698038,357051,44846
    SPARK_USER -> hadoop
    SPARK_YARN_CACHE_FILES_VISIBILITIES -> PRIVATE,PRIVATE,PRIVATE
    SPARK_YARN_MODE -> true
    SPARK_YARN_CACHE_FILES_TIME_STAMPS -> 1477040367079,1477040367425,1477040367454
    SPARK_HOME -> /usr/local/spark-2.0.0-bin-hadoop2.6
    PYTHONPATH -> /usr/local/spark-1.6.1-bin-hadoop2.6/python/lib/py4j-0.9-src.zip:<CPS>{{PWD}}/pyspark.zip<CPS>{{PWD}}/py4j-0.9-src.zip
    SPARK_LOG_URL_STDOUT -> http://datanode01-bi-dev:8042/node/containerlogs/container_1476081972773_0194_01_000003/hadoop/stdout?start=-4096
    SPARK_YARN_CACHE_FILES -> hdfs://10.104.90.40:8020/user/hadoop/.sparkStaging/application_1476081972773_0194/spark-assembly-1.6.1-hadoop2.6.0.jar#__spark__.jar,hdfs://10.104.90.40:8020/user/hadoop/.sparkStaging/application_1476081972773_0194/pyspark.zip#pyspark.zip,hdfs://10.104.90.40:8020/user/hadoop/.sparkStaging/application_1476081972773_0194/py4j-0.9-src.zip#py4j-0.9-src.zip
  command:
  {{JAVA_HOME}}/bin/java -server -XX:OnOutOfMemoryError='kill %p' -Xms1024m -Xmx1024m -Djava.io.tmpdir={{PWD}}/tmp '-Dspark.driver.port=26087' '-Dspark.ui.port=0' -Dspark.yarn.app.container.log.dir=<LOG_DIR> -XX:MaxPermSize=256m org.apache.spark.executor.CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend --driver-url spark://CoarseGrainedScheduler@10.104.90.41:26087 --executor-id 2 --hostname datanode01-bi-dev --cores 1 --app-id application_1476081972773_0194 --user-class-path file:$PWD/__app__.jar 1> <LOG_DIR>/stdout 2> <LOG_DIR>/stderr
.......
.......
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pi.py", line 39, in <module>
    count = sc.parallelize(range(1, n + 1), partitions).map(f).reduce(add)
  File "/usr/local/spark-2.0.0-bin-hadoop2.6/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/rdd.py", line 802, in reduce
  File "/usr/local/spark-2.0.0-bin-hadoop2.6/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/rdd.py", line 776, in collect
  File "/usr/local/spark-2.0.0-bin-hadoop2.6/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/rdd.py", line 2403, in _jrdd
  File "/usr/local/spark-2.0.0-bin-hadoop2.6/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/rdd.py", line 2338, in _wrap_function
  TypeError: 'JavaPackage' object is not callable
```

It's obvious that yarn lanuched the executor using Spark 2.0 and causing the problem which fail the job.

I checked every corner I could think of like related to the setting of spark environment and nowhere can I found spark 2.0.

In ~/.bashrc, I have:

```
export PYTHONPATH=$SPARK_HOME/python/lib/py4j-0.9-src.zip:$PYTHONPATH
export SPARK_HOME=/usr/local/spark-2.0.0-bin-hadoop2.6
```

The folloing command gave empty result:

```
grep -rnw /usr/local/spark-1.6.1-bin-hadoop2.6 -e spark-2.0.0-bin-hadoop2.6 
grep -rnw /usr/local/hadoop-2.6.3 -e spark-2.0.0-bin-hadoop2.6
```

I tried the above scenario on both namenode and datanode only to get the same result.

However, the java Pi example can run successfully.

```
spark-submit --master yarn --deploy-mode cluster --class org.apache.spark.examples.SparkPi /usr/local/spark-1.6.1-bin-hadoop2.6/lib/spark-examples-1.6.1-hadoop2.6.0.jar 100
```

Can anyone share the light on why yarn load the wrong version of spark?

***Update:***

The problem actually resulted from my PATH being messed up. So after I cleaning up the path and set spark 2.0 to be the default version of spark submit. Everything works fine now.

Comment: what do you mean by "nowhere can I found spark 2.0" ? It is in your bashrc...

Comment: I mean whithin those yarn-site.xml , core-site.xml and spark-env.sh file. No setteing related to spark 2.0 can be found.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29691028/can-i-have-multiple-spark-versions-installed-in-cdh My problem is setting spark related environment on date nodes's ./bashrc which is unnecessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start by commenting out your `.bashrc` exports and removing them from environment - they are incompatible. `PYTHONPATH` uses spark 1.6 libs and `SPARK_HOME` points to spark 2.0.

Then run examples by using absolute path to `spark-submit` on both versions -  `spark-submit` sets `SPARK_HOME` based on its location, so it should work in both versions.

Comment: As you can see in the question I was trying to run spark 1.6 and have set $SPARK_HOME to where version 1.6 is. So the PYTHONPATH pointed to was corrrect. But I got your idea. The ptoblem did result from my PATH being messed up. After cleaning the PATH, I had set spark 2.0 to be the default spark submit version.

Comment: There is no need to set $SPARK_HOME to 1.6 or 2.0: If you wat to use `spark-submit` with specific version just call `spark-sumit` with absolute path. Look at the beginning of this script: if SPARK_HOME is not set, it sets it properly.